# Find the domain of: $f(x)= \sqrt[e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}] {\arccos \frac{x-1}{x+2}}$

Tags: functions

> Find the domain of:
>   $$ f(x)= \sqrt[e^{\frac{1}{x^2-1}}] {\arccos \frac{x-1}{x+2}}$$
>   (it's not really visible but it's the $e^{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}$-th root)

I started solving this problem like this:

condition #1

$$-1\le \frac{x-1}{x+2} \le 1$$

1. case
   $$\frac{x-1}{x+2} \ge -1$$
   $$\frac{2x+1}{x+2}\ge 0$$
   $$\Rightarrow x\in (-\infty,-2]\cup[-\frac12,\infty)$$
2. case
   $$\frac{x-1}{x+2} \le 1$$
   $$\frac{-3}{x+2} \le 0$$
   $$\Rightarrow  x\in(-2,\infty)$$

Intersection of these two cases is $x \in [-\frac 12, \infty)$.

condition #2

$$x^2+1 \neq 0$$
$$x \neq \pm 1$$

But, what am I supposed to do with the whole  $e^{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}$-th root?

Comment: but this is another function as in your title

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner fixed it!

Comment: note that $$x^2+1>0$$ for all real $x$

Comment: and $$e^{1/(x^2-1)}>0$$  and it must be $$x^2-1\ne 0$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you ensure that
$$
A(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}
$$
is defined, then also $e^{A(x)}$ is defined (and positive), so you can take any nonnegative number to the power $1/(e^{A(x)})$. This requires $x\ne-1$ and $x\ne1$.

Since the arccosine takes its values on $[0,\pi]$, the condition becomes
$$
-1\le\frac{x-1}{x+2}\le1
$$
This becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{2x+1}{x+2}\ge0 \\[6px]
\dfrac{-3}{x+2}\le0
\end{cases}
$$
The top inequality is satisfied over $(-\infty,-2)\cup[-1/2,\infty)$, the bottom inequality over $(-1/2,\infty)$. Hence the domain is
$$
[-1/2,\infty)\setminus\{1\}
$$